# Including multiple associations using respond_with

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, respond-with

I have a rails 3 app running on ruby v. 1.9.3 with a *user*, *post* and *role* model. A user has many posts as well as roles.

My routes.rb file look like this:

```
namespace :api, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
  resources :users do
    resources :posts
    resources :roles
  end
end
```

I want to include the associated posts **and** roles in the json response when listing all the users. I have found a way to include only **one** of them, like this:

```
#users_controller.rb
def index
  @users = User.all        
  respond_with @users, :include => :posts
end
```

Which gives me the following json response

```
[{
"created_at":"2013-06-17T13:10:59Z",
"id":1,
"username":"foo"
"posts":[ a list of all the users posts ]
}]
```

But what I want is a result looking like this:

```
[{
"created_at":"2013-06-17T13:10:59Z",
"id":1,
"username":"foo"
"posts":[ a list of all the users posts ]
"roles":[ a list of all the users roles ]
}]
```

How should I modify my code to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

u can use 'include' as

```
User.all.to_json(:include => [:posts, :roles])
```

refer http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Serialization/to_json for more info