# respond_with when used in index does not include nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, respond-with

I have the following classes with a `has_one` relationship and I want to return it nested in JSON in my `index` method.

```
class QuantitySample < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :quantity, :dependent => :destroy
  ...

class Quantity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :quantity_sample
  ...
```

I want to use `respond_with` on the **index** method to return each of the quantity samples and the quantity object associated with each one:

```
class QuantitySamplesController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json
  def index
    quantity_samples = current_user.quantity_samples
    respond_with quantity_samples, :include => {:quantity => {}}
  end
  ...
```

I don't get the nested / included quantity objects with the above code. However, if I replace `respond_with` with `to_json`:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json do
    render :json => quantity_samples.to_json(:include => {:quantity => {}})
  end
end
```

The `:include` works!

Full JSON results: With `respond_to` I get:

```
{"quantity_samples"=>[{"id"=>1, "start_date"=>"2016-01-04T07:38:40.694Z", "end_date"=>"2016-01-04T07:38:40.694Z", "user_id"=>1, "workout_id"=>nil, "created_at"=>"2016-01-04T07:38:41.328Z", "updated_at"=>"2016-01-04T07:38:41.328Z", "quantity_type"=>"HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDistanceWalkingRunning", "device"=>nil, "metadata"=>nil}]}
```

vs. with `to_json`:

```
[{"id"=>1, "start_date"=>"2016-01-04T07:36:09.415Z", "end_date"=>"2016-01-04T07:36:09.415Z", "user_id"=>1, "workout_id"=>nil, "created_at"=>"2016-01-04T07:36:10.110Z", "updated_at"=>"2016-01-04T07:36:10.110Z", "quantity_type"=>"HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDistanceWalkingRunning", "device"=>nil, "metadata"=>nil, "quantity"=>{"id"=>2, "value"=>4200.0, "unit"=>"m", "created_at"=>"2016-01-04T07:36:10.123Z", "updated_at"=>"2016-01-04T07:36:10.123Z", "name"=>nil, "quantity_sample_id"=>1}}]
```

Why isn't this working with `respond_with`?

Comment: Could this be an answer to your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17213052/including-multiple-associations-using-respond-with

Comment: @Mingsheng I read that before — I also tried the syntax used there `respond_with quantity_samples, :include => :quantity` and that didn't work either

Comment: By what I understand, it sounds like specifying include under the first loc:    quantity_samples = xxx.include(...).to_json;   or however it's like described in the other question.. I'm sorry I don't really deal with responders that much myself so I can't help a lot here either :/. Laptop's dead too and I can't try either. I'll see if I can come up with a working sample if nobody answers by e end of day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to work for me. I just replicated what was done in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17213052/including-multiple-associations-using-respond-with) supplied

```
respond_to :json
def index
  quantity_samples = current_user.quantity_samples.to_json(include: :quantity)
  respond_with quantity_samples
end
```